# impl trait for multiple errors handling

Tags: rust

Is it possible to do something like this? If not why?

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = foo() {
        println!("Error: {}", e);
    }
}

fn foo() -> Result<(), impl Error> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;
    let _: i32 = buffer.parse()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:10:24
   |
10 | fn foo() -> Result<(), impl Error> {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `impl Traits` are resolved to a concrete type statically, at compile-time. Here you are trying to return two different types which implement `Error`: `std::io::Error` and `std::num::ParseIntError`. Since the `impl Trait` has to be resolved to only one type during compilation, there is no way this can be done.
2. The `?` operator calls `From::from` to convert between error types, which means it is flexible with regard to the target type. Here, the target type is an `impl Trait`, so the compiler does not have enough information to know which exact type to choose.

For these reasons, `impl Traits` are not really the right tool to use here. You can solve this by one of:

- Use `Box<dyn Error>` as the return type. This implements `From<E>` for `Error` types so the conversion will work automatically. But it will require a dynamic allocation.
- Implement a new error type as an enum which can contain any of the error types returned by the function, and implement `From<ErrType>` for each of those types.